# How to have emissionMap without being washed out with some colour?

Tags: three.js, webgl, react-three-fiber

So, I'm trying to emulate a laptop screen in ThreeJS, so there's a video texture on it which I'd like to glow. Doesn't need to be a light source, it just needs to be illuminated.

I've tried using `emissionMap` of the texture with `emission` of `0xffffff` (white) but it just comes out real grey and washed out. Trying with red (`0xff0000`) shows the video glowing red (obviously), and `0x000000` just doesn't show anything.

How do I just get the `emissionMap` to glow by itself, without being really washed out with some other colour? I've also tried:

- Same settings with `MeshBasicMaterial`, `MeshLambertMaterial`, `MeshPhongMaterial` and `MeshToonMaterial`. Same with all
- Just setting `map` and `color` (i.e, without `emission`/`emissionMap`). Also totally washed out

Am I doing something wrong, or is it impossible to just have an `emissionMap` without having to choose a colour to completely wash it out with? Can I *just* have the texture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

did you try to set encoding of your videoTexture to THREE.sRGBEncoding?

```
videoTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an emissiveMap to control the intensity of the emission on different parts of the mesh.

[Here it is in the three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.emissiveMap)